# How know have internal hip rotation or postirior or anterior pelvic tilt

Tags: strength, hip, physical-therapy

My left leg is internally rotated. But I don't know that I have internal rotation or anterior or postirior pelvic tilt. My left knee also paining badly and my walking is not properly. Don't know how to fix it. If you know let me know.